# How to nuke aws if aws-nuke mostly fails

Tags: aws-nuke

In general aws-nuke fails removing resources e.g. S3 buckets, dynamodb tables. Is there any other solution before closing the credit card?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about AWS administration, not programming.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Any suggestions where to move this question?